# ASP Classic On IIS Takes 31 Seconds To Execute Each mySQL Script

Tags: mysql, iis, vbscript, asp-classic

My development system has suddenly been afflicted with this weird problem where every single SQL script takes exactly 31 seconds to execute on my Classic ASP site's connection to a mySQL (MariaDB) database.

Connecting to either a local copy of the DB running off my system or even my live DB being hosted at a web host, it all the same.
Everything from a simple

```
adoconn.Execute("SELECT * FROM users;")
```

or even

```
adoconn.Execute("SET sql_mode''")
```

would take 31 seconds to execute. Each!

I can safely rule out any problems with the DB as connecting to it and running scripts from DBeaver shows no problems at all. The results come back instantly. 
I can also rule out network problems as the local DB and the hosted DB have the same results and I have used WireShark to confirm that the MySQL packets are being responded to almost immediately from the hosted DB.

Debug stepping through my ASP code, everything runs fine right up until the .Execute() at which it will take 31 seconds, regardless of how complex the script is.

The strangest thing is, this problem just came out of the blue; when my system was powered down, disconnected and untouched over the weekend. No updates, installations or changes were done to the system. Friday I was doing my dev work perfectly fine. But Monday morning when I powered it back up, the DB connections there are stuffed.

I've already tried configuring mySQL to use the "skip-name-resolve" and "bind-address = ::" settings.
I have tried rebuilding my IIS websites and reinstalling IIS itself.
I've also reinstalled mySQL ODBC drivers on my system to no avail.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the cause of this whole issue was the **McAfee** software that came pre-installed in my Dell laptop.
No, I did disable the firewall and antivirus, mind you.
Those were the first steps I did and triple-checked routinely during my testing. Both McAfee's firewall and auto-protection were **all fully disabled**.
But apparently, McAfee, ignores this setting and was screwing my DB connections over ODBC.

This problem finally only came to an end when I fully uninstalled this McAfee **malware**. There's no other way to describe it.

Let this post be a warning to anyone else naively believing this malware to be anything else.